# Naming PHP object and SQL issue.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, multidimensional-array

In a php file called: loadPosts.php
I am connecting to a database and retrieving a VARCHAR, VARCHAR, TEXT, TEXT, and VARCHAR. Each of them have an undefined length and I am trying to put the data into an object. Here is my php code.

```
    <?php

//Creates an array to keep track of all information being past back to java script
$info = array();

$i = 0;
$j = 0;

//If server sends a post method then execute script
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    requestPosts($info);

    //Encode the array to be sent to the java script with all the return messages and the state
    echo json_encode($info);
}

function requestPosts(&$info){
    //Set name of server, username, password, and database to access
    $servername = "";
    $username = "";
    $passwordSQL = '';
    $dbname = "";

    //Create database connection
    $con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $passwordSQL, $dbname);

    //Check connection
    if ($con->connect_error) 
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
        $info["message"] = "failed";
    }else{
        $info["message"]= "You're Connected!";
    }

    //Create a query for account name
    $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM posts;";

    //Send query and assign to result
    $result = $con->query($sqlQuery);

    //If result is set
    if($result){
        //If result has rows found
         if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
            {
                //Loop through result
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    $info[$i][$j] = $row;
                    $j += 1;
                }
            $i += 1;
            }
    }
}
?>
```

Here is my javascript for calling and retrieving the data:

```
$(function(){
   $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'assets/php/loadPosts.php',
            success: function (msg) {

                //Console log the message
                console.log('msg', msg);

                //Create an object from the message
                var obj = JSON.parse(msg);
                console.log('obj', obj);

            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert('Form Error' + msg);
            }
        }); 
});
```

When I retrieve the data from my java script I get this:

[Return Code in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYVCB.png)

I would like to know if it is possible to name the object element in the array that contains all the children objects, as well as having the first object inside the parent object having the name of 0 instead of "".

Thanks in advance for any help or thoughts! I'm sure it's simple and I am just being dumb, but I would love the help! Thanks :)

Comment: What if you start counting $i and $j from 1? It won't follow the index rules but the naming issue will be fixed.

Comment: I tried :/ didn't work. I also am trying to name the element in the array as well.

Comment: Try this `$info[][$j] = $row;`

Comment: Semi worked. It created elements in the array named 0 through X numbers. But then each of those elements had an object bundled in it named "". I figured out I could name the element by initializing a null element with a name, assigning the null element to the object found from the database, and then removing the old object element that had no name. But I still haven't found out how to name the first object as 0 instead of "".

Comment: Can you post the new response, after using `$info[][$j] = $row;`